# Java Finding a Key with a Certain Value in a Properties File

Tags: java, file, properties, key

So basically I have a program where you can add an account by typing in info then clicking add account, then it saves the account in a properties file with an ID to differentiate it from other keys (the ID gets incremented by one each time an account is added) and displays the username to the JComboBox, so you can select the account. The problem is when it comes to removing an account. I can easily get the text in the combo box and remove the item on the combo box, but I can't get the ID of the account from the selected item on the JComboBox so I can delete they key in the properties file. Here's an example of my properties file : account1 = username;password
account2=user135;pass123

So the solution that I thought to this problem (but I don't know how to do) is getting the username text from the selected JComboBox and searching for a key that has a value equal to the username, and then delete that key. Is this possible? If not is there another way I could get the account ID?

Edit: I learned that sqlite is a much better way of storing account data - thanks for the answers :)

Comment: That is a very poor usage of properties files.  That's not what they're for. You should be using a database to store account information.  However, we can't explain how to do that on SO, you need to read up on databases. SO is for specific programming questions and is not a tutorial site.

Comment: I'm new to java I/O, and i'm just looking to save the accounts on the user's computer, so mysql wouldn't really be beneficial. Would you be able to link me to something that would be good for my situation?

Comment: http://www.tutorialspoint.com/sqlite/sqlite_java.htm
SQLite for java

Answer (score 2):

A couple things here.

First and most important: 
I really hope you are not saving user's passwords in plain text.  This is very bad security practice.  I hope you are at least hashing them with a salt.  Also when that happens you still have an issue of how you send it to a server to verify it is the correct password if this is supposed to be an auto login.  You could encrypt the password instead.

You may want to consider using SQLite to be a database that holds your account information.  Note you should still hash or encrypt the passwords.

With that said if you have to use a properties file, I might consider use a different form of data to group all the data together.  For example XML or JSON.

```
accounts = [{"un":"username1", "pw":"password1"}, {"un":"username2", "pw":"password2"}]
```

If that would not work for you and you like the idea of a separate property for each account then consider using a HashMap to store an account name to property variable.  When you save the data out or load it you would do something along the lines of:

```
//defined somewhere
HashMap<String, String> accountToProperty;

accountToProperty.put("username1", "account1");
accountToProperty.put("username2", "account2");
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer I will check out sqlite :)